# SP13: Move Site to Publishing

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, publishing-site, public-website

I am running into some trouble.  The problem is that I am trying to move a SharePoint Subsite page from the test environment into public (publishing) environment.  The idea was to use SharePoint Designer, but I do not know all the steps to take once in Designer.  Do I simply change the URL to match the publishing URL's?

Comment: Are you trying to move just the theme itself?

Comment: @jasonflaherty I am trying to move the entire subsite. I believe the only way to move Subsites are by using SP Designer.